# Checking gitlab repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I recently created a gitlab account and added a ssh key to it. There is a tutorial on gitlab website that says that one can use ssh -T git@name.com to check if the process was well succeed. If it was, it should give the user welcome. When I try to do it with:

```
ssh -T git@asmf2.com
```

I receive:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname asmf2.com: Name or service not known

I tried too:

```
   ssh -T asmf@asmf2.com
```

because amsf@asmf2 is what shows up on my gitlab page. I receive a e-mail with the title:

> SSH key was added to your account
>   So I do not know which names should be used with the ssh command.
>   How can I figure this out?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You had it right the first time, the issue isn't git or ssh it's that you haven't set the dns records for asmf2.com to point to your gitlab instance. Please do so, if you can't do so use the ip address of the server hosting your instance instead, like so:

```
ssh -T asmf@x.x.x.x
```

If you aren't running your own instance but instead you are using [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com). Use this:

```
ssh -T asmf@gitlab.com
```

Comment: Hi, I used the ssh -T asmf@gitlab.com command and received this:                The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (52.167.219.168)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is b6:03:0e:39:97:9e:d0:e7:24:ce:a3:77:3e:01:42:09.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,52.167.219.168' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. Connection closed by 52.167.219.168      I tried again and received: Permission denied (publickey).
Somthing went wrong?

Comment: Are you using your own instance of gitlab or are you using the one on gitlab.com

Comment: It think it is the one on gitlab.com, because of the ping stuff VonC tell did not work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed gitlab on your own instance (asmf2.com), you need to make sure that instance is reachable from your localhost:

```
ping asmf2.com
```

(resolve any dns issue)

And then you need to add it to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` folder:

```
ssh-keygen -R asmf2.com
ssh-keygen -R [ip_address]
ssh-keygen -R asmf2.com,[ip_address]
ssh-keyscan -H asmf2.com,[ip_address] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H [ip_address] >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H asmf2.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Replace `asmf2.com` with `gitlab.com` if you are using Gitlab.

Finally, you can test gitlab with:

```
ssh -T asmf@asmf2.com
```

Although gitlab is generally installed with the git account, so that would be:

```
ssh -T git@asmf2.com
```

If you are using gitlab:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

(the user is always git)

And you should receive a `Welcome` message.

Comment: When I issue a "ping asmf2.com". I receive:
"ping: unknown host asmf2.com". So am I using the one on gitlab.com. How should I proceed now ?

Comment: @SérgioAvelleda the same answer applies. Replace asmf2.com with gitlab.com. And replace user asmf with git.